# How to match up values between two tables with linked IDs in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes in R, where both have a column called "typeid".

Dataframe A looks like this:

```
Shirt  Typeid
1      2
2      2
3      1
4      3
5      1
```

Dataframe B looks like this:

```
Typeid  Color
1       Red
2       Blue
3       Green
```

Is there a way to add the corresponding Color values from df B to df A, matching them according to typeid? I'd want the end product to look like this:

```
Shirt  Typeid   Color
1      2        Blue
2      2        Blue
3      1        Red
4      3        Green
5      1        Red
```

any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `merge`

```
merge(A, B)
```

or `match`

```
A$Color <- B$Color[match(A$Typeid, B$Typeid)]
```

Comment: that did the trick, thanks!